# ng2-charts error while testing Angular app

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ng2-charts

I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBasePixel' of undefined` when I run my tests with a component that contains a chart. I'm not sure what's going on, I tried looking things up but I didn't find anything that was relevant. I have the test import the charts module, and I can't really think of anything else that could be wrong. The only ideas I have are maybe the charts module being imported in the async beforeEach means it's not available right away to the component? Or maybe since it's rendered in a "smaller" browser, it's not working correctly? I can't figure it out.

My test looks like this:

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { PlantsService } from '../plant/plants.service';
import { MockPlantsService } from '../plant/plants.service.mock';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
  let component: DashboardComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;
  let plantsService: PlantsService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ChartsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        DashboardComponent,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        DashboardComponent,
        { provide: PlantsService, useClass: MockPlantsService },
      ],
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    plantsService = TestBed.inject(PlantsService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

and the component:

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartDataSets, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import { Color, Label } from 'ng2-charts';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Plant } from '../plant/plant.model';
import { PlantsService } from '../plant/plants.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css'],
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public isLoading = false;
  private plantSub: Subscription;
  private plantInfoSub: Subscription;
  public plantList: Plant[];
  public selectedPlant: Plant;

  // Chart configuration stuff goes here, Removed for brevity

  constructor(private plantsService: PlantsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.plantsService.getPlants();
    this.plantSub = this.plantsService.getPlantsUpdateListener().subscribe((plantData: { plants: Plant[] }) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.plantList = plantData.plants;
      if (this.plantList) {
        this.getPlantInfo(this.plantList[0]);
      }
    });
  }

  getPlantInfo(plant: Plant) {
    if (!plant) { return; }
    this.plantsService.getPlantInfo(plant.id);
    this.plantInfoSub = this.plantsService.getPlantInfoUpdateListener().subscribe((plantInfo: { plant: Plant }) => {
      plant = Object.assign(plant, plantInfo.plant);
      this.lineChartData = [Plant.getChartData(plant.humidityHistory, 'Humidity')];
      if (plant.soilMoistureHistory) {
        this.lineChartData.push(Plant.getChartData(plant.soilMoistureHistory, 'Soil Moisture'));
      }
      this.lineChartLabels = Plant.getPlantHistoryTimestamp(plant.humidityHistory);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.plantSub?.unsubscribe();
    this.plantInfoSub?.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Stack trace:

```
 at <Jasmine>
    at ChartElement.updateElement (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js:5931:1)
    at ChartElement.update (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js:5903:1)
    at ChartElement._update (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js:3831:1)
    at ChartElement.reset (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js:3733:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js:9638:1
    at Object.each (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js:2227:1)
    at Chart.update (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js:9637:1)
    at Chart.construct (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js:9357:1)
    at new Chart (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js:9294:1)
    at BaseChartDirective.getChartBuilder (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/ng2-charts/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ng2-charts.js:677:1)
```

Comment: from your error message, it seems like there is a piece of code that is trying to call or access the `getBasePixel` property of an object that is undefined. since `getBasePixel` doesnt appear in your code sample, it's probably happening inside a different function.

if the error message came with a stack trace, that could be helpful in diagnosing which function is causing this. otherwise you could also try commenting out lines of code one by one until the error stops to narrow the problem down to the line that is causing it

Comment: @MoralCode I included a stack trace above. It seems to be external to my code. I'm wondering if I should just switch over to ngx-charts since the ng2-charts maintainer is no longer maintaining it.

Comment: it could be that your `  // Chart configuration stuff goes here, Removed for brevity` may actually be necessary. it looks like theres an issue on [github](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/266) for `ng2-charts` where someone in the comments seemed to have this same error and solved it by putting the axis settings "in options, not data". Hopefully that helps!

Comment: @MoralCode That stuff is actually formatted correctly in the actual file, I removed all that for this post because stack overflow wasn't allowing me to post it since most of my question is code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up switching over to ngx-charts since ng2-charts is no longer being maintained. No issues during testing anymore.

Comment: I see in NPM last publish 4 months ago [ng2chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts).